# List of function calls in static code analyzer tools

Tags: c, static-analysis, function-calls

In an embedded C project which is using a SDK's source and header files, I want to have a list of functions, definitions, and variables that a specific source file is using **across the project**. In other words, a tool that **statically** analyzes and lists dependencies of a specific source code without the need to execute functions ( not dynamic) of the source file.

I checked static code analysis tools, but they are mostly linters and do not give me a list of dependencies.

I think this type of work is not being explored by the community and any answer will help a lot.

Thanks

Comment: What about pointers? file1.c: int a; file2.c: int *p = &a; file3.c: *p = 1;

Answer (score 1):

You can try [CppDepend](https://www.cppdepend.com) and its code query language, here's an example of a cqlinq query to get all methods with their files used by a source file.

```
from m in JustMyCode.Methods where  m.SourceDecl.SourceFile.FileName=="test.cpp"
from mc in m.MethodsCalled
select new { m,mc,mc.SourceDecl.SourceFile.FileName}
```